# Wire Params MaxPlus

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

I'm trying to work out how to wire params in MaxPlus.
MaxScript:

`paramWire.connect obj1.transform.controller[#Position] obj2.pos.controller[#X_Position] "-Position.x"`

~~

Here's what I have so far:

```
import MaxPlus as mp

Xsl = [node for node in mp.SelectionManager.Nodes]  # list all sected objects
Xsl0 = Xsl[0]  # turn into variable for autocomplete

const = mp.Factory.CreateFloatController(mp.ClassIds.Float_Wire)  # Create Float wire controller

sub = Xsl0.GetSubAnim(2).GetSubAnim(0)  # Grab the Translate sub anim

sub.AssignController(const, 0)  # Assign constraint to translate x
```

So, this assigns the Float_Wire to the object in question, I just need to work out how to assign the expression and connect it between obj1 and obj2.

Any advice on this would be appreciated.